# Rich Javascript UI Frameworks, EXT, DOJO and YUI

Tags: javascript, extjs, yui, dojo

### Disclaimer & Long Winding Question Approaching

I know topics like this have been beaten to death here so suffice to say I'm not asking about which framework is better, I don't really care about opinions on the better framework. They all do pretty amazing things.

### The Question

Given that I have an existing web application, made of mostly regular HTML+CSS (jQuery where needed), which is the optimal framework to integrate a few "rich" pages into typically a regular stream of HTML.

### Reason

I am trying to bring our proven application into the realm of awesome desktop like UI but I want to do it one small piece, one screen at time. But for our users, support personel and especially me taking it slow is the only option.

Also, with our branding requirements having a framework that just takes over the viewport isn't an option, it has to play nice with other HTML on the screen.

Imagine the example being a rich user manager in an otherwise plain HTML+CSS environment.

### Experience Thus Far

**Dojo + Dijit**
*Pros*: The new 1.5 widgets plus the claro theme is the cure for what ails us. Dojo seems to be able to use markup to create the UI which is very appealing and has a fair amount of widgets.

*Cons*: Holy bloated lib Batman! Dojo seems to be enormous and I have to learn a custom build system to get it to stop requesting 4,800 javascript files. This complex empire of Javascript makes me believe I won't be able to create much that isn't already there.

**ExtJS**
*Pros*: Amazing set of widgets, does everything we could possibly want. Seems quick, every version brings new improvements.

*Cons*: I'm not sure how to use this without the entire display being EXT. I'm still building a web site, so I would prefer something that could integrate into what we already have. Some pointers here would be great.

**YUI**
*Pros*: Well, it's Yahoo isn't it? AWS console is downright wicked. Plenty of support and a giant community.

*Cons*: Well, it's Yahoo isn't it? AWS console is the only wicked thing. Complex for someone who's used to jQuery.

### Help Me

I am willing to accept experience, links to ways to solve problems I've outlined, new toolkits (even though I'm pretty sure I've seen most by now) or even just advice.

Comment: Only Jquery can save you . :)

Comment: I want to use jQuery UI so badly. But the style is weird, and there is no layout manager or toolbar. Piecing those components together is possible, but I was hoping not to have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding ExtJS, it's pretty easy to start it in an existing div with something like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    App = new Ext.Panel({...})
    App.render('div-id')
});
```

The App panel can then have it's own layout manager.

Comment: I took your advice and spent a bit more time trying to mess with EXT. I have gotten some basic stuff in a div which is improving my opinion of the library. Is there another way to learn ExtJS without just deconstructing demo pages?

Comment: Starting from the samples and checking the docs for other things you can do with each widget is the best way, I think. You can find even more good samples in the 'User Extensions and Plugins' part of the forums. Every time you want to do something, start by searching the forum, someone else might have done a plugin from which you can learn.

Comment: There's also Saki's page, for even more documented samples: http://examples.extjs.eu/

Comment: You can buy the ExtJS In Action ebook from manning, but digging into the code is the best way to learn.

Comment: I concur with these guys.  I'd recommend learning the nuances of the different layout managers first to get your feet wet with Ext.  By using these technique above, you <should> be able to mix different libraries across different sections of your page.

Comment: +1 for ExtJS In Action. Essential reading to get you up and running.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer here. Although, as a jQuery user I'm going to spend a bit more time there just to see what comes out of it. Hopefully when I'm done I'll have a jQuery and an EXT version of my UI... decision should be clear at that point.

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful if you're familiar with jQuery, but not yet familiar with YUI 3 syntax: http://www.jsrosettastone.com/

Each of the libs you listed is excellent.  When embarking on a larger scale project, the quality of a lib's documentation, community, and commitment to support become more relevant.

Comment: This is a great page (bookmarked) but I'm speaking more to the UI side of things, not just the core.

Comment: "When embarking on a larger scale project, the quality of a lib's documentation, community, and commitment to support become more relevant".well said man, just well said.

Answer (score 2):

With Dojo, keep in mind that outside of dojo base, it only ever loads what you tell it to.  But yes, without a built layer, that means it could easily end up requesting 50 JS files at startup for a large application using a bunch of widgets.

- There are several pages in the reference guide documenting the build script: http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/index.html
- Rebecca Murphey wrote a nice blog post outlining an example app and build profile that you might find illuminative: http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/scaffolding-a-buildable-dojo-application
- If you get stuck, there's likely to be people in the Dojo IRC channel that can help.

RE ExtJS: I'm not sure what your exact situation is, but keep in mind that if you're intending to use it in commercial non-open-source software, you need to pay for licenses: http://www.sencha.com/store/js/

I'm a little curious as to why you think the size / number of requests is specifically an issue with Dojo though.  I haven't used the others, but I'd expect it to be somewhat of a potential concern with any of them.